# What is the preferred image size & aspect ratio for Quick Links which is using Grid layout + which are inside 2 columns section with vertical section

Tags: sharepoint-online, page-layout, modern-pages, quick-links

I have a modern SharePoint page which have a vertical section + 2 columns layout. inside the first column i have a Quick Link web part named "Marketing" which is rendered using the Grid layout (showing Picture-1 & Picture-2) as follow:-

[image]

now i am not sure what is the best aspect ratio and image size in my case. now based on this link https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/image-sizing-and-scaling-in-sharepoint-modern-pages-dc510065-b5a5-4654-bc94-e3ecbbb57d8d that Quick link using Grid layout is best displayed using aspect ratio 16:9, as follow:-

[image]

but not sure about the image size, now based on this table, am i considered using Two columns or three columns layout? as in my case i use Two columns with a vertical section:-

[image]

any advice?